# What did they use for their toast?

Tags: kill-la-kill

In episode 17 of *Kill la Kill*, Kiryūin Satsuki brings out a toast to their success with what looks like a cup of sake. But, considering it is a school and they are between the ages of 16 and 19, they shouldn't be allowed to drink this yet, right? So what did they toast with?

[image]

Comment: Do you realize that they have just returned victorious from a war in which they established control over all Japan? Who, exactly, do you think is going to stop them from drinking alcohol?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely to be a Sakazuki, which are  small to medium-sized ceremonial cups during a celebration, most commonly used at weddings and other special occasions such as tea ceremonies. The Yakuza are know for their particular initiation ceremony where the initiate exchanges Sakazuki with the Oyabun (Boss) as a vow of loyalty.

[image: Two cups no girl.]

As for the underage drinking, the legal drinking and smoking age is 20 in Japan. Typically it's socially acceptable to drink a little for celebrations.

Comment: So you are saying that was sake?

Comment: Yes, it's probably sake.

Comment: If not it's a soft drink like like [Pocari Sweat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocari_Sweat).

Answer (score 2):

I heard that was water. 
I thought that was sake, too.

That is called Mizu-Sakazuki (Hai). 
It means final water in life.
Breaking cup means that, too.

Before battle against strong enemy (Kiryuin's mother), they did that.

The scene was talked about in Japan, too.

Comment: Oh wow, did not even know that existed. I think that fits the plot a bit better then original sakazuki. " The ceremonial drinking of water(mizu sakazuki) was customary among soldiers immediately prior to battle.This old samurai custom was a means of praying to the gods for good luck..."

Comment: This is true as far as I know, but can you add some references for that?

Comment: episode 22 or 23, Sakazuki stopped her mate to break their cups.that was not sake.